# Convert STL file to usable character

Tags: texturing, rigging, stl

I'm still fairly new to Blender and have now found 2 great Tomb Raider figures that I would like to use as characters in my scenes. Means I would like to rig them and of course provide them with the appropriate textures. (I'm not sure if the figures already have textures).

My question is now, is it possible to edit an stl file in Blender so that I get a rigged Tomb Raider figure at the end?

Attached are the links to the figures:

1: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-print-models/art/sculptures/angelina-jolie-lara-croft-3d-printable-stl

2: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-print-models/art/sculptures/lara-croft-tomb-raider-fan-art-statue-12d2335f-90e8-4817-829a-40ce3ecc55a2

Kind regards
David

P.S. Unfortunately I found "only" one Tomb Raider figure with Angelina which is at least already manipulated and looks very good. But it also costs a lot of money.

Comment: The models seem to be high-poly sculpts. Such models are not suitable for animation because the huge amount of vertices results in bad performance. The messy topology causes deformations. Also, it can create massive lags and crashes when you try to UV unwrap, texture and weight paint them. You need to convert them into low-poly versions for rigging and animation. This process is called "[retopology](https://youtu.be/S4YNiImIgPs)".

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! So if i change this to a low poly version i could start use this? =)